# Remove date and year duplication inside a string inside a list

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have this kind of list(example):

```
mylist = [[20,'September 2015, August 2013, September 2016, September 2015'], [30, 'August 2012, August 2012']]
```

And desired output is this:

```
mylist = [[20,'September 2015, August 2013, September 2016'], [30, 'August 2012']]
```

Basically I want to remove a date and year from that string each time exact date and year is repeating like in my example (September 2015 it was repeating - must be the month and year), I will have some bigger strings but they are same like my example, how I can achieve my desired output? Thank you! I use python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that ordering is not important:

```
>>> [[tup[0], ', '.join(d for d in set(tup[1].split(', ')))] for tup in mylist]
[[20, 'August 2013, September 2015, September 2016'], [30, 'August 2012']]
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I have to accept this answer since it was the quickest, I will look the other also to understand their approach!

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over your items in a loop and reassign. You would benefit from the use of `collections.OrderedDict` for dropping duplicates.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

for i, l in enumerate(mylist):
     mylist[i] = [l[0], ', '.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l[1].split(', ')).keys())]

print(mylist)    
[[20, 'September 2015, August 2013, September 2016'], [30, 'August 2012']]
```

This assumes that your dates are separated exactly by `,`, and if this isn't the case, a more involved solution is needed.

Comment: Thank you, I will look more into this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that converting a list to set removes the duplicates. The example below does just that - splits the string to a list, converts it to a set, converts is back to a list, joins it back to a string.

```
mylist = [[20,'September 2015, August 2013, September 2016, September 2015'], [30, 'August 2012, August 2012']]
newlist = []
for item in mylist:
    newlist.append([item[0], ", ".join(list(set(item[1].split(", "))))])
print(newlist)
```

Note that the order of the months may not be preserved - set is not ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
 map(lambda x: [x[0]] + list(set([i.strip() for i in x[1].split(',')])), my list)

[[20, 'August 2013', 'September 2015', 'September 2016'], [30, 'August 2012']]
```

Comment: I will also check this, thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution abusing generators and list comprehensions - the python way (tm)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mylist = [[20,'September 2015, August 2013, September 2016, September 2015'], [30, 'August 2012, August 2012']]
mylist = [
  [x[0], ", ".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys([y.strip() for y in x[1].split(",")]).keys())]
  for x in mylist
]
```

I'm accounting for weird formatting in the list items, only assuming that the list is separated by `,`, at the very least (so `September 2010,September 2010`) will still be picked up and formatting properly)

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with the order being messed up, you could change it to a set and change it back to being a list. Using your example:

newlist = [[sublist[0],', '.join(set(sublist[1].split(', ')))] for sublist in mylist]

running it on my end, this is the output:

[[20, 'August 2013, September 2015, September 2016'], [30, 'August 2012']]
2012, August 2012', 30]]